# How to show that a sequence converges pointwise but not uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that the sequence $f_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, given by $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2+nx}n$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$, converges pointwise but not uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Look up the definitions of pointwise and uniform convergence.  Pointwise asks that for a given $x$ and $\epsilon$ you can find a $\delta \ldots$.  Uniform asks that given $x$ you can find a $\delta \ldots$ that is independent of $x$  You can disprove uniform by showing that for any $\delta$ you can find an $x$ that violates the given $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite $$ f_n(x)=x+\frac{x^2}n.$$So, pointwise, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=x
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

As for the uniform convergence, the problem is that for $x$ big enough, you need a big $n$ to control the square. Given a fixed $n$, if you take $x=\sqrt{n}$ then 
$$
|f_n(x)-x|=\frac{x^2}n=\frac nn=1.
$$
This negates the uniform converge. More explicitly, given $\varepsilon=1$, for every $n_0$ there exists $n>n_0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$ with $|f_n(x)-x|\geq\varepsilon$.